# How do i call specific row and column data from an array after querying a database... (mysqli php)

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

**THE QUESTION:**

I would like to use one single database query to store information into an array...

I would like to then be able to call say **ROW** "3", **COLUMN** "ARTIST" from the results and place that in different areas of my website as many times as i like without re-querying the database.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR**

I am able to query a database and display that information on screen but i know this is a step in the wrong direction of what i actually need..

```
<?php
```

require_once("DbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT `artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, `picture` FROM historylist ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 3";

$result = $db->query($sql);

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {

    $artist = $row->artist;
    $title = $row->title;
    $label = $row->label;
    $albumyear = $row->albumyear;

echo "$artist<br> $title<br> $label<br> $albumyear<br>";
}
```

?>

I believe i need to use a fetch_assoc so that when i fetch the results it binds them to the column name but i could be wrong..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put in an array for easy access later:

```
$albums  = array();
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
    $albums[]['artist'] = $row->artist;
    $albums[]['title'] = $row->title;
    $albums[]['label'] = $row->label;
    $albums[]['albumyear'] = $row->albumyear;
}

echo $albums[2]['artist']; // gets the third row artist.
```

We use the key "2" to get the third row since PHP uses zero-based indexes for its arrays. If you want to  use the key "3" to refer to third row, just use your own counter when creating your array.

```
$albums  = array();
$i = 1;
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
    $albums[$i]['artist'] = $row->artist;
    $albums[$i]['title'] = $row->title;
    $albums[$i]['label'] = $row->label;
    $albums[$i]['albumyear'] = $row->albumyear;
    $i++;
}

echo $albums[3]['artist']; // gets the third row artist.
```

Comment: Errrm, John.  Did you test that first snippet???